# Use object literal as TypeScript enum values

Tags: angular, typescript, enums

I have an enum:

```js
export enum PizzaSize {
  SMALL =  0,
  MEDIUM = 1,
  LARGE = 2
}
```

But here I'd like to use some pair of values: e.g. `SMALL` I would like to say that it has a `key` of `0` and a `value` of `100`. I endeavor to use:

```js
export enum PizzaSize {
  SMALL =  { key: 0, value: 100 },
  // ...
}
```

But TypeScript doesn't accept this one. How can I do this?

Comment: I don't think it's supported yet.. https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1206

Comment: any changes to this since 2016?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

### Update: find [@Javarome's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51398471/3744431) below, which is more elegant. I suggest using his way.

If you need to use Type, try adding some code. 
usage: `getPizzSizeSpec(PizzaSize.small).value`

```
enum PizzaSize {
    small,
    medium,
    large
}
interface PizzaSizeSpec {
    key: number,
    value: number
}
function getPizzaSizeSpec(pizzaSize: PizzaSize): PizzaSizeSpec {
    switch (pizzaSize) {
        case PizzaSize.small:
            return {key:0, value: 25};
        case PizzaSize.medium:
            return {key:0, value: 35};
        case PizzaSize.large:
            return {key:0, value: 50};
    }
}
```

Comment: Check out my recent answer, it also has the benefit of exhausiveness checks

Comment: This answer is no way close to object literal enum. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51398471/2103767 is by far the best by @Javarome

Answer (score 202):

TypeScript [supports numeric or string-based enums](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html) only, so you have to emulate object enums with a class (which will allow you to use it as a type in a function declaration):

```
export class PizzaSize {
  static readonly SMALL  = new PizzaSize('SMALL', 'A small pizza');
  static readonly MEDIUM = new PizzaSize('MEDIUM', 'A medium pizza');
  static readonly LARGE  = new PizzaSize('LARGE', 'A large pizza');

  // private to disallow creating other instances of this type
  private constructor(private readonly key: string, public readonly value: any) {
  }

  toString() {
    return this.key;
  }
}
```

then you can use the predefined instances to access their `value`:

```
const mediumVal = PizzaSize.MEDIUM.value;
```

or whatever other property/property type you may want to define in a `PizzaSize`.

and thanks to the `toString()` overriding, you will also be able to print the enum name/key implicitly from the object:

```
console.log(PizzaSize.MEDIUM);  // prints 'MEDIUM'
```

Comment: Way more elegant than the accepted answer but, the constructor should be private constructor(private key: string, PUBLIC value: any) {} to be able to use PizzaSize.MEDIUM.value or define a getter to it

Comment: True @Flohlich. Just added a getter to forbid change of such an enum constant.

Comment: this answer is unclear to me, can you show the `enum` declaration not just the `PizzaSize` class?

Comment: @Alexander Mills There is no enum declaration, that’s the point : as there is no support for object enum you have to emulate it through a class declaration.

Comment: I'd suggest to declare the static items `readonly` as well. Else wise they could be reassigned externally (`PizzaSize.SMALL = PizzaSize.LARGE; // get a big pizza, but pay small :-)`).

Comment: This is much more elegant. I would use your way too. Upvoted.

Comment: How can use this in angular html template?

Comment: @j1s In the relevant component, declare a public property this has the name name as the enum and is equal to it: `PizzaSize = PizzaSize`. Then you'll be allowed to write `PizzaSize.LARGE` in your template.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `toString()` method or the arguments into the constructor?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out.  The internal read only variables are instances of the class.  Got it!

Comment: Be careful using this approach if you clone your objects with `Ramda`/`lodash`, e.g `R.clone({pizza: PizzaSize.MEDIUM})` or `_.cloneDeep`. Triple equals and `switch` statements won't work like they do with TypeScript `enum`

Comment: I wish this gave exhaustiveness checks :( That's often the main reason I want to use an enum
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYEMDOa4AUCWAvPFAZX2DgG8AoASDRhRhwTimBQBMIA7JATziIBZAIIAZUXDgBeOF2AB3bPkIk8wABQByIWNGaANHE3C4aALYokSOGGUpNASgDcNOgyYs2nHv0EBRABEASQBVQWlZBSUCYlItf2CwgyMTM2B2HABXMxs7RxdaekZmVg5uPjhRYQAlAHE-SRk5RVwY1Q1NKrq-ZOM4VCgAczJbGPzKGjAoHAA3BjIEbjooTIQYaHUaalLvCoBrYF4ALlMYaa5B-S2d8v45pEzgE5QuXhoHCgBfSm-KADNMlw1jhuHA-uowCdWipSA4TsscBcKK55DgYAgABZwCEAOgOvA+VGo1AQ6DI2hE4k0J1YMEyUC4Rk0W1JaHJCVCgmpnjpDKZLLJRi69W5tPpjM0zOo30+QA

Comment: is there no way not to duplicate the literals? ("MEDIUM" is used twice, as a name and then as a parameter)

Answer (score 32):

As of [Typescript 3.4](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html), you can use a combination of `keyof typeof` and [`const` assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) to create objects that can have the same type safety as enums, and still hold complex values.

By creating a `type` with the same name as the `const`, you can have the same exhaustiveness checks that normal enums have.

The only wart is that you need some key in the complex object (I'm using `value` here) to hold the name of the enum member (if anyone can figure out a helper function that can build these objects in a typesafe way, I'd love to see it! I couldn't get one working).

```
export const PizzaSize = {
    small: { value: 'small', key: 0, size: 25 },
    medium: { value: 'medium', key: 1, size: 35 },
    large: { value: 'large', key: 2, size: 50 },
} as const

export type PizzaSize = keyof typeof PizzaSize

// if you remove any of these cases, the function won't compile
// because it can't guarantee that you've returned a string
export function order(p: PizzaSize): string {
    switch (p) {
        case PizzaSize.small.value: return 'just for show'
        case PizzaSize.medium.value: return 'just for show'
        case PizzaSize.large.value: return 'just for show'
    }
}

// you can also just hardcode the strings,
// they'll be type checked
export function order(p: PizzaSize): string {
    switch (p) {
        case 'small': return 'just for show'
        case 'medium': return 'just for show'
        case 'large': return 'just for show'
    }
}
```

In other files this can be used simply, just import `PizzaSize`.

```
import { PizzaSize } from './pizza'

console.log(PizzaSize.small.key)

type Order = { size: PizzaSize, person: string }
```

Also notice how even objects that are usually mutable can't be mutated with the `as const` syntax.

```
const Thing = {
    ONE: { one: [1, 2, 3] }
} as const

// this won't compile!! Yay!!
Thing.ONE.one.splice(1, 0, 0)
```

Comment: It does seem a little tricky. And it doesn't allow you to add functions to the "enum" values like the class does. But this give exhaustiveness checks where the class doesn't, so it's just a choice of tradeoffs I'm afraid.

Comment: FYI my tsc `3.9.7` is complaining about `order(PizzaSize.large)` with `Argument of type '{ readonly value: "large"; readonly key: 2; readonly size: 50; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '"small" | "medium" | "large"'`. So it doesn't behave like enums in that way.

Comment: Yeah this solution isn't exactly like enums, it's just parallel, using the keys of a `const` object instead of an actual enum value. Pass `order(PizzaSize.large.value)` or `order('large')` and everything will compile. Doing that is just as typesafe as an enum.

Comment: In terms of building the values of the enumerated objects in a typesafe way, the best I could think to do was to cast each declaration as I defined it. It's a little more verbose than I'd like, but it seems to get the job done.

Comment: You can reference this pattern as enumeration classes

Comment: can you explain what does `export type PizzaSize = keyof typeof PizzaSize ` do? I removed it and the code was still working as expected

Comment: @Qiimiia it exports that type for other files. It isn't necessary for it to work correctly in the current file.

Answer (score 24):

I think to get to what you want, something like this will work

```
interface PizzaInfo {
  name: string;
  cost_multiplier: number;
}

enum PizzaSize {
  SMALL,
  MEDIUM,
  LARGE,
}

const pizzas: Record<PizzaSize, PizzaInfo> = {
  [PizzaSize.SMALL]: { name: "Small", cost_multiplier: 0.7 },
  [PizzaSize.MEDIUM]: { name: "Medium", cost_multiplier: 1.0 },
  [PizzaSize.LARGE]: { name: "Large", cost_multiplier: 1.5 },
};

const order = PizzaSize.SMALL;
console.log(pizzas[order].name);  // "Small"
```

Comment: is there any way to make compilation fail if you add a value to `PizzaSize` if you forget to modify  `pizzas`?

Answer (score 5):

Object.freeze makes it read only and prevents more properties being added:

```
const pizzaSize = Object.freeze({
  small: { key: 0, value: 25 },
  medium: { key: 1, value: 35 },
  large: { key: 2, value: 50 }
})
```

Comment: Only first level. You should also freeze each deeper level.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a typed const to achieve this:

```js
export const PizzaSize: {
    [key: string]: { key: string, value: string };
} = {
    SMALL: { key: 'key', value: 'value' }
};
```

Optionally you can extract the type information to separate interface declarations:

```js
interface PizzaSizeEnumInstance {
    key: string;
    value: string;
}

interface PizzaSizeEnum {
    [key: string]: PizzaSizeEnumInstance;
}

export const PizzaSize: PizzaSizeEnum = {
    SMALL: { key: 'key', value: 'value' }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Old thread, but I came up with something similar to [@Jerome](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51398471/21584187). It's my attempt at making a sealed class

```
module SealedPizzaEnum {
    abstract class PizzaBase {
      constructor(public topping: string) {}
    }
    export type Spec = PizzaBase;

    export class Cheese extends PizzaBase {}
    export class ThreeMeat extends PizzaBase {
        addMoreMeat() {
            console.log("Meeaaattt");
        }
    }
}

function makeADaPizza(pizza: SealedPizzaEnum.Spec) {
    if(pizza instanceof SealedPizzaEnum.Cheese) {
        console.log(pizza.topping);
    } else if (pizza instanceof SealedPizzaEnum.ThreeMeat) {
        pizza.addMoreMeat();
    }
}

makeADaPizza(new SealedPizzaEnum.Cheese("pineapple"));
makeADaPizza(new SealedPizzaEnum.ThreeMeat("Onion"));
```