# TypeScript enum with objects

Tags: typescript, enums

I am attempting to use [Javarome's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51398471/2379279) to [a previous TypeScript question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41179474/use-object-in-typescript-enum) regarding how to use an object in an enum:

```
class Material {
  public static readonly ACRYLIC = new Material(`ACRYLIC`, `AC`, `Acrylic`);
  public static readonly ALUM = new Material(`ALUM`, `AL`, `Aluminum`);
  public static readonly CORK = new Material(`CORK`, `CO`, `Cork`);
  public static readonly FOAM = new Material(`FOAM`, `FO`, `Foam`);

  // private to diallow creating other instances of this type.
  private constructor(
    public readonly key: string,
    public readonly id: string,
    public readonly name: string
  ) {}

  public toString(): string {
    return this.key;
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, I am running into an issue later in the code when I attempt to use bracket-syntax (because it's in a `for-of` loop):

```
const materials: string[] = [`ACRYLIC`, `FOAM`];
for (const materialKey of materialsArray) {
  const material: Material = Material[materialKey];
  // ...
}
```

That pops up a huge TS error [TS(7053)] with the following message:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'typeof Material'.
>
> No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'typeof Material'.ts(7053)

I have been Googling for hours but have found nothing that helps. Is there any way to reference this "enum" using bracket-syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with this code is exactly:

```
const materials: string[] = [`ACRYLIC`, `FOAM`];
```

There is no relation between possible properties of `Material` static class and a list of strings. The key to the problem is to specify in type that the list which we have is a list of only allowed properties which have values as `Material` type.

It can be achieved by [Exclude](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetu) type utility. Take a look at below example:

```
type MaterialKeys = Exclude<keyof typeof Material, 'prototype'>;
const materialsArray: MaterialKeys[] = [`ACRYLIC`, `FOAM`];
for (const materialKey of materialsArray) {
  const material: Material = Material[materialKey];
  // ...
}
```

For more informations: `Exclude<keyof typeof Material, 'prototype'>;` will take all keys of `Material` type and exclude from it the `prototype`, so we will in result have all static fields, and that is what we want though.

Comment: You, sir, are a genius. Thank you so much for your help!