# Search predefined instances of Typescript class

Tags: typescript, types

This is a complement of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41179474/use-object-literal-as-typescript-enum-values)

Lets say i have this class:

```
export class PizzaSize {
  static readonly SMALL  = new PizzaSize('SMALL', 'A small pizza');
  static readonly MEDIUM = new PizzaSize('MEDIUM', 'A medium pizza');
  static readonly LARGE  = new PizzaSize('LARGE', 'A large pizza');

  // private to disallow creating other instances of this type
  private constructor(private readonly key: string, public readonly value: any) {
  }

  toString() {
    return this.key;
  }
}
```

I can access the values of the properties by doing this:

```
console.log(PizzaSize.MEDIUM); 
console.log(PizzaSize.MEDIUM.value);
```

But i need a function that i pass the value, and it returns me the corresponding instance of the class

Example:

```
searchInstancesOfClass('A small pizza');
```

I want it to return me the SMALL instance;

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be a simple matter putting all the objects that you want to search through into an array, and then searching in that array.

```
  static searchInstancesOfClass(value: string): PizzaSize | undefined {
    const staticPizzas = [
      this.SMALL,
      this.MEDIUM,
      this.LARGE,
    ]
    return staticPizzas.find(pizza => pizza.value === value)
  }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAKCWAvRYDKSCm0DeAoa0EALmEfMNAE4ZgAmA9gHYgCe0qAsgIIAyPBAXmiMMAdzhIU6RBgAUAck68e8gDTR5XQgFswIENAAOksPICUAbnyESZCtTpNW0DgFEAIgEkAqh2hCRcQRkNEwFNy9fNQ0tbQxaeABXbSMTcysCYlJyKhoGZjYeLgAlAHFXQWExCRDpOXkistdozWhwSgBzLGMQ9NxrAHoBo0p4ADdSLCJ6aASIPRB6cWAHMkYO6HoiAAsMSmh4RizGYAwYegAzaB34GCIWQwxrQ1GJoixgJmJKROBpylkL3Gk1yjgK0AA1hgWAAuGyjdbqQyJABGIByDnyzgmIESGDhYEYLDMOGsAF9+plbDkIDRKMBtp4jiQTmcAPIXADC4CgshxeLh30OHTMcOCUkw0AAPtBEoxaBgLod4qSCARPsybNlgOLIP5oABtaxq67bW4AOiUfFUxrVNwg5oiPg4NpNBHt5sa5VdaoAurbqEREpRGFq7LqHUr5YCTP4AHypELm-lYARp6ApszkynXeioIgIjqyEl4E2B4Ohj1QlgZaAUim4DUQeggDDmxZF3V1c20sD0xnMwmnCAc7mQCAKLQQXT6RMocz+dNdzCW7h8LNDNr0DoQOEFvFAA)